Can't Use my Build and Run settings in another system (QT Creator)
Recently I tried to create a one project and collect my projects in these project. I wrote a new pro file and "CONFIG" setting, now if I wrote terminal "CONFIG+=press" and then run make it builds press, but I don't want to use it in terminal, so I added this settings to UI. In my build settings for every project I added Qmake setting for "CONFIG" command.
Now the problem is I can use my custom run and build settings in my system but in different systems I can't use this settings in qt creator. I don't want to set this configurations for every system.
I tried few methods, like changing "pro.user" file writing a new "pro.shared" file. I saw this method in offical qt documentation (it was for cmake but use qmake) and tried it. With this method I couldn't do it. I always see the messagebox about problems about shared file or user file. I know that user file is unique but I tried to rename shared file as user file. even this method didn't work as it expected. I just want to use path of executable and qmake commands. so how could I save this settings for different systems.

Can't you include this settings in your pro file?

I can, But I wanted to create a new shared file for skipping this step. After opening the project in qt creator, configuration shown but as an vanished target. so there are two option after selecting vanished target, first copying steps to another hit or create new one. isn't there easiest way to do that like automatic creating new kit?
